# Android: How to make Google Map Polyline smoother?

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

I'm using the latest Google Maps Android SDK:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
```

This is my method for adding a Polyline to the map

```
return mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(latLngs)
                .width(Globals.MAP_TRACK_WIDTH)
                .startCap(new RoundCap())
                .endCap(new RoundCap())
                .geodesic(true)
                .color(resources.getColor(R.color.light_green)));
```

The polylines seem to be very rugged and I'd like them smooth. Is this even possible?

[image]

I found a reference to Polyline Quality in the docs but I don't see this property available on Android.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/reference/rest/Shared.Types/PolylineQuality

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have the same need actually. Couldn't find a solution yet. I'm just drawing the Polyline and am able to adjust width and color, but nothing on stroke ui. I wanted similar smoothness to the image i shared below. 
       

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iZEs.png